# При загрузке на хостинг не отображаются картинки из папки icons

Tags: html, css

При загрузке на хостинг не отображаются файлы из папки icons, хотя на локальном сервере всё нормально,
вот ссылка на сайт https://gloopt.000webhostapp.com/

бьюсь уже 2й день

Так выглядит на локалке
[image: Так выглядит на локалке]
Пишет эту ошибку

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Вот все файлы на сервере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гугле увидел что нет такой папки, но не понимаю почему он её не видит, она ведь есть в файлах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это значит, что у вас или нет такой папки или название файла не такого или и то и другое

Comment: Папка icons есть, а вот нужных иконок в этой папке нету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если откроешь окно разработчика (f12) то есть раздел sources и там нет папки icons почему то, значит это папка не грузиться на твой хост по какой то причине, попробуй перименовать папку icons на img2 или на подобную. Или если тебе нужны просто иконки то попробуй не скачивать иконки а по CDN подключить, как вариант https://fontawesome.com/ или на подобных сайтах можно иконки и не скачивать.

Comment: Не знаю каким чудом, но твой совет с переименованием помог, спасибо большое
Только я что то не понимаю почему не грузилась папка icons